# Determining that a function's maximum lies on boundary conditions by using partial first-order differentials to prove no critical points exist?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations, proof-explanation, boundary-value-problem

Background: I am going through the first proof in [J. Mark Keil and Carl A. Gutwin's *Classes of Graphs Which Approximate the Complete Euclidean Graph*](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/BF02187821.pdf). The proof ultimately needs to analyze a function's maximum values.

Given the bounds $\varphi>0$, $\theta\ge\varphi$, and $\theta+\varphi\lt\pi/3$, and:

$$
f\left(\theta,\varphi\right)=\left(\frac{2}{3}\pi-\theta\right)\frac{\sin{\varphi}}{\sin{\left(\pi/3+\theta\right)}\sin{\left(\varphi+\theta\right)}}+\frac{2\pi\sin{\theta}}{3\cos\left(\pi/6\right)\sin\left(\varphi+\theta\right)}
$$

The question is: how does the paper determine the "magic value" of $\pi/10$ that is used in the following statement:

> With these constraints it can be shown that $\frac{\partial f}{\partial\theta}\ne0$ if $\theta\ge\pi/10$ and $\frac{\partial f}{\partial\varphi}\ne0$ if $\theta\le\pi/10$.

(It is then justified in only analyzing the boundary conditions on $f\left(\theta,\varphi\right)$ after this statement, but I have been stuck understanding this particular step in the proof)

I believe the typical strategy is to analyze the critical points of $\frac{\partial f}{\partial\theta}$ and $\frac{\partial f}{\partial\varphi}$ by determining where such functions have a value for zero, and then examining $\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial\theta}\right)^2f$ and $\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial\varphi}\right)^2 f$ and $\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial\theta}\right)\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial\varphi}\right)f$ to determine whether such critical points are minimums, maximums, or saddle points.

However, I have computed $\frac{\partial f}{\partial\theta}$ and $\frac{\partial f}{\partial\varphi}$, and it is not clear to me how $\pi/10$ arises as a critical point. Also, it is clear that this function is not the most straightforward to compute second-order derivatives of. In lieu of analyzing critical points, is $\pi/10$ chosen as an arbitrary value by the authors? And is it chosen as part of a strategy to simplify the analysis: since they are able to prove the partial first-order derivatives are never both zero for any single value of $\theta$, there cannot be any critical points within the bounds given for $f\left(\theta,\varphi\right)$? How does one then justify the choice for $\theta=\pi/10$?